# Extract value from Row object

Tags: sql, presto, trino

Following the office documentation https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/map.html. I use "map_entries" break map into array(row(K, V)) structure. My question is how to extract K and V value from the row object? Currently I have to recast it to a Row object that I defined.

```sql
select 
    type.n , type.b
from
    (select  
         CAST(type AS ROW(n VARCHAR, b VARCHAR)) as type
     from 
         search.yli_tmp_trevi_requests_mini
     cross join 
         unnest (map_entries(cast(json_extract(req, '$.types') as MAP<VARCHAR, VARCHAR>))) t (type)
    ) t
where 
    type.n = 'apple'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What version of Presto are you running? Recent versions of Trino (formerly known as Presto SQL) ([0.207+](https://trino.io/docs/current/release/release-0.207.html)) fixed an issue to make UNNEST return multiple columns when unnesting arrays of rows, as expected by the SQL specification.

This is how you would do it in the [current](https://trino.io/docs/current/) version of Presto:

```sql
SELECT t.n, t.b
FROM <table>, UNNEST (map_entries(...)) t(n, b)
WHERE t.n = 'apple'
```